# State array gets emptied after a method call

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, bind

I am trying to perform a filter on a React state array. From the render I call the search method.

Somehow the state array gets emptied from the moment I call:

- `this.startSearch.bind(this)`.

So the method can't use the state array because it is completely empty.

```
export default class ItemList extends Component {
  state = {
    itemList: []
  }

  startSearch(input) {
    console.log(this.state.itemList)
  }

  render() {
    //load Json
    let filteredArray = Data.filter(
      (item1) => {
        return
        item1.title.indexOf(this.state.searchInput.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) !== -1;
      }
    )
    this.setState({ itemList: filteredArray })

    return (
      <input type="text" id="inputField" value={this.state.searchInput} onInput={this.startSearch.bind(this)}></input>
    )
  }
}
```

Any idea what I am missing out here?

Comment: Can you share more of your code from the component ?

Comment: ^^ ideally, update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, preferably a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @DJYadav I've added more code to the question.

Comment: Can you add the part where you fill the array or as T.J. said, a runnable snippet of your code, pls?

Comment: There are many issues in code. 1) There is no variable Data and you have written return before filter logic runs 2) You don't setState inside render method. 3) filteredArray logic should be in onChange or onInput handler of input element. Please correct those issues and edit the question so that we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

this.startSearch need to do (e)=> this.setState({searchInput:e.target.value})
but if it's on react native, i don't think onInput work